# Spring security not working with Grails project on JBoss Application Server

Tags: grails, spring-security, jboss

I have a big(multiple custom plugin based) Grails project, which runs perfectly fine on Tomcat server.

Now for a new customer we need to deploy it on JBoss Application server. It seems to deploy fine without any error but when I try to login on the first page which is implemented using Spring Security plugin. It does not log me in. I have tried going to a valid URL to check if its a problem of redirecting but it is not the case.

Please note it is not showing any error on the log. And since it is not properly executable in development environment so each time I need to build a WAR file to test it.

Grails version: 2.4.4

Spring security version: ':spring-security-core:2.0-RC4'

JBoss version: wildfly-9.0.2.Final

Comment: Tested Spring Security on a empty new project and it is still the same case. Spring security is not working with JBoss. Any one have any idea?

Comment: @BurtBeckwith Can you suggest anything? Anyone with good experience in Grails please suggest something.

Comment: Have you tried turning on debug level logging for spring security and see what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

I tried some setups, and they all worked as a simple new project.

I used grails 2.4.4 and spring-security 2.0-RC4.

Here are a few things you could try:

- Use latest spring-security version 2.0.0

  ```
  compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:2.0.0"
  ```
- Add [jboss plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/jbossas) and [generate deployment xmls](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-jbossas/docs/manual/guide/2%20Usage.html) (this is needed for grails 2.5.4)

  ```
  build ':jbossas:1.0'

  $grails generate-boss-deploy 6
  ```
- Create a brand new Wildfly install and deploy your app.

I can only think about a infrastructure problem, since I got no problem with the same setup. I running on Mac, with java 8 and Wildfly 9.0.2 final. Tested grails 2.4.4 and 2.5.4, spring security 2.0-RC4 and 2.0.0.

Best,
Eder